# Jquery cycling through multiple images and showing 3 at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, animation, effects

Can you please point me to a jquery plugin, or a snippet I can use to 
make this?

Here's the question: Say I have 12 images and I want to show 3 at a time 
and cycle through the 12 in this fashion:

(img1-img2-img3) then (img2-img3-img4) then (img3-img4-img5)...

See what I mean? In fact, I want a kind of marquee for images.

Is this doable?

Thanks a million times! :)

Comment: cycle based on what -- clicking a "next" button?  timer?

Comment: timer, thanks for asking ferocious!

Answer (score 3):

a nice looking plugin that does what you need can be found here:

http://www.agilecarousel.com/examples/multi_example/carousel.html

Josh

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! English being my 4th language, I was looking for that word I forgot : Carousel! Thanks a lot! I also found this plugin: jCarousel-lite. http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo The auto scroll demo is definitely what I'm looking for! Again thanks :)